# I am unable to submit my application on Free Basics. How do I report bugs or give feedback on the Free Basics onboarding tool?

Tags: facebook, submission

When submitting my application to the Free Basics / Internet.org on-boarding tool, I get an error message saying: There was an error processing your request. Please try again later.

The error message is very vague and there is nowhere to report the problems / bugs.

Is anyone else experiencing same problem? Any possible solution to this problem?

EDIT 10/Nov/2015: Unfortunately I am stuck at the submission page. I did some digging and Firefox developer console throws the following error:

21:19:22.128 This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.1 partners.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

A new Support tab will be available today on the Free Basic portal to report issues on any submission. It will not be shown if you don't have any pending submission though.

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck at the submission page. I did some digging and Firefox developer console throws the following error:

21:19:22.128 This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.1 partners.facebook.com